# C/C++ detect network type

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, network-programming

I need to write a win32 c/c++ application which will be able to determine whether the PC it's running on is connected to one of 2 networks.  The first network is the company LAN (which has no internet connection) and the second network is a standalone switch with a single PC connected to it (the PC that the program is running on).

I'm pretty new to network programming but so far I have tried testing to see if a network drive which is held on our LAN can be mapped.  This works fine if the PC is connected to the LAN, the drive mapping succeeds so so LAN detection is successful.  However, if the PC is connected to the switch, this results in a VERY long timeout which is not a suitable as it will delay the program so much as to make it unusable.

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions?

I'm using c/c++ in VS 6.0

[Update]

Whilst trying a few different ideas and looking at some of the suggestions below I thought I should update with some additional information as many (if not all) of the suggestions I don't think will work.

(1) The aforementioned LAN has no external connections at all, it is completely isolated so no resolving of external DNS or pinging websites is possible.

(2) Hostname, MAC address, IP,  Default Gateway, Subnet etc etc (basically everything you see in ipconfig -all) are all manually configured (not dynamic from the router) so checking any of these settings will return the same whether connected to the LAN or the switch.

(3) Due to point (2), any attempts to communicate with the switch seem to be unsuccessful, in fact almost all networking commands (ping, arp etc) seem to fail - I think due to the machine trying to connect to the LAN when it isn't there :-(

One thing I have found which works is pinging the default gateway IP which times out when connected to the switch.  This is sort of ok as I can reduce the timeout of ping so it doesn't just hang for ages but it feels like a bit of a hack and I would certainly appreciate any better solutions.

Thanks

Comment: unrelated to the problem but: you are really using the old compiler from 1998?

Comment: So what you have is two different networks that are configured identically so that software can't tell the difference, and now you want to tell the difference with software.

Comment: @akira Unfortunately yes. This is legacy code and due to the complexity of the software and our testability constraints, the company are reluctant to update compiler.  If they did it would result in having to do a full system test which takes a team of 3 people upwards of 6 weeks to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try to differentiate between the two using information available locally--that is, from your computer.  Does the output of `ipconfig /all` differ depending on which network you're connected to?  If so, exploit that difference if you can.

Is it possible to get the MAC address of the standalone switch?  Of the switch that controls the company LAN?  That would be a sure way to tell.  Unless somebody cloned the MAC address.

If you try using the existence or non-existence of some network service to determine which network you're connected to, you can never be sure.  For example, if you failed to map that network drive, all you know is that the network drive isn't available.  You can't say for certain that you're not connected to the company LAN.  Same is true if you use ping.  Lack of response from a particular machine means only that the machine didn't respond.

Comment: Some of these suggestions won't work (please see updated question) I do know the MAC address of the standalone switch though, how can I use this? Sorry for being a noob, I do appreciate the help!

Comment: @Gavimoss: The Windows `arp` command will show you the MAC address of the machine connected at a particular IP address. That is `arp -a 10.77.76.1` will show you the IP address and the MAC address. You can access that data in your program through the IP helper APIs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073(v=VS.85).aspx  If you know the MAC address of the standalone switch, then you can compare that against the value returned by `arp` (or the IP Helper function that you call).

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting, this was a side project that I just came back to finish off and your solution works perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as TCP/IP is concerned there is no such thing as a LAN on WAN. There are a set of non-internet routable addresses like 192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x but these are sometimes used by ISP short of IP addresses.

You best bet is to use Asynchronous APIs when making TCP/IP connections. WIN32 defines a whole buch of OVERLAPPED APIs for this purpose. This will prevent your application from grinding to a halt while waiting for a remote connection.

Alternatively put the socket stuff into another thread and then only notify the UI when the operation is done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the LAN on WAN comment. To clarify my description, I just meant that our LAN is isolated so I cannot do something like ping Google for example (this seemed to be a commonly offered solution on forums I searched for network detection issues).  Also, putting the socket stuff in another thread will not work as the application cannot run until it knows which network it is connected to so it would have to wait any way.

Answer (score 0):

Various things you can look at for differentiation:

```
DNS domain name (GetComputerNameEx)
MAC address of gateway (ping it, then GetIpNetTable)
Routing table(do you have a gateway and default route on the company LAN)
WNet discovered network resources (WNetOpenEnum, WNetEnumResource)
Ability to resolve external hostnames (try a 5-10 names like www.google.com, www.microsoft.com and so on, if one resolves you should have internet)
```

You'll have to decide how many indicators are "enough" to decide you're on one or the other LAN though if tests fail. Then keep retrying until you have a definite result.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366071%28v=VS.85%29.aspx has a lot of network related functions that you can experiment with to create further indicators.

Comment: I just updated my question - bearing in mind the new information, will any of the above still work?